# Routing websocket destination in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

Having raw websocket implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new MessageHandler(), "/websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .addInterceptors();;
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public class MessageHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        // The WebSocket has been closed
    }
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        String auth = (String) session.getAttributes().get("auth");
        System.out.println(auth);

        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("You are now connected to the server. This is the first message."));
    }
    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage textMessage) throws Exception {
        // A message has been received

    }
}
```

The websocket client connect to server ( handshake etc. ) with `/websocket` url e.g `ws://localhost:8080/websocket`

However, now that connection is estabilished is there a way how to route messages? Lets say i have app that provides chat and some pop-up functionality ( for simplicity lets say the user sends pop-up message and some pop-up window shows to all of his friends in app ).

Ofcourse i would like to route chat messages to `/chat` and popup to `/popup`.

One way how to achieve this is to send json message to server and parse it there e.g:

```
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage textMessage) throws Exception {
        String path = getRouteFromJsonMessage(textMessage);
        if( ! "".equals(path) && path.equals("chat")
           ....
        if( ! "".equals(path) && path.equals("popup")
          ....

    }
```

But this seems too slow, parsing json on every message. Is there some other, better way how to achieve routing?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Btw, shorter and quicker to read: `if ("chat".equals(path))` instead of `if( ! "".equals(path) && path.equals("chat")`

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt thanks , i jut added the code to the question just to demonstrate, didnt rly think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just register two different MessageHandlers

```
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new ChatMessageHandler(), "/chat")
                    .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                    .addInterceptors()
                .addHandler(new PopUpHandler(), "/popup") //etc;

    }
}
```

Comment: wouldnt 2 web socket connections be created in this case? Lets say the app has milion users that are connected, in that case you would have to save 2 milions web socket connctions instead of 1 mil. Or am i wron?